# Second display does not turn on after sleep

Tags: fedora, multi-monitor, sleep, nouveau

After my machine (Fedora 35) goes to sleep and wakes, my second monitor won't turn on again. I can reproduce the same problem by running

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --off 
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --auto
```

The second command will output `xrandr: Configure crtc 3 failed`, without turning on the monitor. For some time now, my Problem Reporting shows a system failure "xorg-x11-drv-nouveau". I do not know if there is a link. My system journal shows the following:

```
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: acr: AHESASC binary failed
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: acr: init failed, -110
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: init failed with -110
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau: systemd-logind[946]:00000000:00000080: init failed with -110
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau: DRM-master:00000000:00000000: init failed with -110
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau: DRM-master:00000000:00000000: init failed with -110
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Client resume failed with error: -110
Feb 13 18:33:46 fedora kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resume failed with: -110
Feb 13 18:33:47 fedora kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Dropped ACPI reprobe event due to RPM error: -22
Feb 13 18:33:47 fedora kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Dropped ACPI reprobe event due to RPM error: -22
Feb 13 18:33:48 fedora abrt-server[3575]: Oops looks like a problem in kernel module, new component xorg-x11-drv-nouveau
```

Thank you!

Comment: I remember a PCI kernel bug regarding ASPM, which kernel version are you using? Does the same happen if you use the driver blob by nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing with my HP Omen with external display (hanging off DisplayPort/Nvidia 2060).

I think it's a timing issue. When the system comes out of sleep, the external monitor takes awhile to wake up. I see a long-ish delay in Windows (like 10+ seconds), but it works. In Linux it never wakes up. I think Fedora is giving up and assuming that the system only has one monitor.

If I press the monitor selection key on my laptop keyboard (Fn-F1 on the Omen keyboard), I can explicitly select "Join Displays" and it immediately wakes the external display.